# C# logging "russian dolls effect" in constructors parameters

Tags: c#, logging, reflection, aop

First, I am not sure that I use the good words to describe my problem, apologies (English is not my mother tong).

It is about adding *loggers* to a project. 
As it was asked, there should be several loggers and they should to be defined "dynamically". 
So we end up with classes that have a `Logger` property.

All constructors have though an extra parameter which is the `logger` instance passed to the constructor with the other business parameters. As we go deep inside the code, classes inside each other are using the same pattern to pass the `logger` instance.

Sure it works, but I am not happy with it. 
What annoys me is that the logger does not belongs to the business logic. 
Maybe there is nothing to do with it.

--

More precisely this is what I am working out for the moment :

- There is the `ILogger` interface that defines the loggers functions (`LogError(string msg)` for example). Different Loggers will implement this interface.
- There is the `ILoggable` interface that will be implemented by all classes that need to do logging. This interface has a property `public ILogger LoggerPte`

I use a static class `LoggerUtility` with a `[ThreadStatic]` field `static ILogger CurrentLogger` and a function :

```
public static void SetLoggerReference(ILoggable loggableClass)
{
    loggableClass.LoggerPte = CurrentLogger;
}
```

Outside of the *loggable* class, the CurrentLogger is defined.

In the constructor of a *loggable* class, I have to call `LoggerUtility.SetLoggerReference(this);`

If found this way more elegant although it might be twisted, but I would like to know if it can be possible to go further...

I have just started to read about custom attributes, reflection and AOP. Can somebody give me a hand about how to use an attribute like `[Loggable]` to automatically make the constructor call the function `SetLoggerReference(this)` after the constructor without having explicitly to write it in the code. 
If it is possible...

Comment: Take a look at PostSharp.  They have a nice solution to this using Aop

Comment: [This](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) article describes a flexible design for building a solution that supports AOP.

Comment: PostSharp would be the could thing to use, but it depends on my team's decision. What I was looking for is not possible in "naked" C#, which is an answer. So I guess I am going to inspire myself from qujck's article. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you hear about Dependency injection desgin pattern? Your original solution is simple constructor injection. Your final solution is Property injection and all your bussines objects need to have LoggerPte property. Please look at some solutions how to deal with dependency injection and build/create your business objects via dependecy injection container (the container will inject the LoggerPte property for you and you don't need to call your static method in each object constructor). I am using [Unity Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647202.aspx) (Microsoft solution) but you can find a lot of others.

I hope it's what you need.